# yii2 : xampp upgrade to php7

Tags: php, xampp, yii2-advanced-app

I have a new project in yii2, I downloaded yii2 using composer and when I try to download the extension it tells me to upgrade my PHP from 5 to 5.6 or higher.  Then I upgraded it to 7.1.3 the old projects works fine and the phpMyAdmin too afterwards I tried to install the extension again.  It gives me the same message.

> Problem 1
>
> - sebastian/version 2.0.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - sebastian/version 2.0.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (5.5.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Installation request for sebastian/version (installed at 2.0.1) -> satisfiable by sebastian/version[2.0.1].

What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: the wrong here is : `sebastian/version 2.0.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (5.5.34)`

Comment: But I upgrade the php to 7 !

Comment: make sure that you've restarted your xampp

Comment: I restarted the xampp .. in debug toolbar  it gives me that I use the php 7

Comment: how could you know your php version ? and try to remove your composer cache

Comment: i used the simple way `echo "Current version is PHP " . phpversion();` the messeage is  Current version is PHP 7.1.3 and i upload a pic

Comment: updating composer uses php cli sapi, which is totally different of the php http server version, you need to make sure that the cli is updated, in linux it's easily by running the command `php -v` , I'm not a windows user so i don't have information about that, you may google about that.

Comment: in windows `composer update` and that's true it works fine now , thank you